# How to fix a pathway error, automatically printing attachments, when I receive multiple emails at the same time

Tags: vba, outlook

This code automatically prints emails, that have attachments, as they arrive, based on rules.

When I receive multiple emails at the same time, it gives me a pathway error.

How do I fix this error so I don't miss emails?

```
Sub LSPrint(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    On Error GoTo OError

    Dim oFS As FileSystemObject
    Dim sTempFolder As String
    Set oFS = New FileSystemObject

    sTempFolder = oFS.GetSpecialFolder(TemporaryFolder)

    cTmpFld = sTempFolder & "\OETMP" & Format(Now, "yyyymmddhhmmss")
    MkDir (cTmpFld)

    Dim oAtt As Attachment
    For Each oAtt In Item.Attachments
        FileName = oAtt.FileName
        FullFile = cTmpFld & "\" & FileName

        oAtt.SaveAsFile (FullFile)

        Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        Set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace(0)
        Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(FullFile)
        objFolderItem.InvokeVerbEx ("print")

    Next oAtt

    If Not oFS Is Nothing Then Set oFS = Nothing
    If Not objFolder Is Nothing Then Set objFolder = Nothing
    If Not objFolderItem Is Nothing Then Set objFolderItem = Nothing
    If Not objShell Is Nothing Then Set objShell = Nothing

OError:
    If Err <> 0 Then
        MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
        Err.Clear
    End If
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: Try using a random number for the folder name, instead of a timestamp (or append a random number to the timestamp)  The will reduce the chance of collisions if multiple mails arrive at the same time.

Comment: What do you mean by this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the following line of code fails:

```
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(FullFile)
```

Make sure the file path string is well-formed and doesn't contain forbidden symbols. Don't forget to specify the filename with an extension.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: How do I make the file path name well formed?